# Rails link models in a form DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, associations, dry

I am trying to link multiple rails models in my app. I am trying to let users create reviews on a product using a form. I am trying to use the rails DRY principle.

I first made a bat table with bat `name`, `model year`, and an `image`. Then I created a manufacturer table which only lists the names of the manufacturers of bats. My bats model `belongs_to :manufacturer` and my manufacturer model `has_many :bats`.

Instead of creating multiple tables using `manufacturer`, (listing the name of the manufacturer at least 3 times for each bat) how can I link my two models together?

My form is submitted to the `review` model. In the form I already have `<%= f.collection_select :bat_id, Manufacturer.all, :id, :manufacturer, include_blank: true %>`, which lists all of the possible manufacturers in a drop down menu. **HOWEVER**, nothing is submitted to the `:bat_id` parameter in the review form when submitted.

--One guess is to have the `manufacturer_id` integer stored in the bat model as an integer under the column `manufacturer_id`(Note: already done this, but I don't know how to submit that in a form?)

--Another guess is to have the bat model inherit from the manufacturer model

Any help is greatly appreciated

My full form:

```
<%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field" align= "center">
    <h3>Select bat</h3>
    <%= f.collection_select :bat_id, Manufacturer.all, :id, :manufacturer, include_blank: true %>
    <h3>What do you like about this bat?</h3>
    <%= f.text_area :pros, placeholder: "Enter what you like..." %>
    <h3>What do you not like about this bat?</h3>
    <%= f.text_area :cons, placeholder: "Enter what you don't like..." %></br>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
  <%= f.submit "Add Review", class: "btn btn-large btn-info" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

the params in the collection_select is supposed to be:

> f.collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id,
>   :name_with_initial, prompt: true)

where post is the Model,author_id is the attribute

or you could try using:

> =f.select( :bat_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@manufacturers,"id","manufacturer",
>   f.object. bat_id),{})

and put the

> @manufacturers = Manufacturer.all

inside the controller

Comment: I cannot get it to work with `:review`. It says "NoMethodError" + "undefined method `merge' for :manufacturer:Symbol"

Comment: Hi, have you tried using the "f.select" from my example?

Comment: I just tried it and got the dropdown box to appear, but it did not submit anything to the `review` table